# Are there rules for 濁音化？

Tags: pronunciation

As far as I know, 濁音化 happens a lot when words are combined together. The following are some examples I know.

1. 三（サン）+ 階（カイ）-> 三階（サン**ガ**イ）
2. 一（イチ）+ 匹（ヒキ）-> 一匹（イ**ッピ**キ）
3. 猫（ネコ）+ 好き（スキ）-> 猫好き（ネコ**ズ**キ）
4. 興味（キョウミ）+ 深い（フカイ）-> 興味深い（キョウミ**ブ**カイ）

To the best of my knowledge, cases like 1 and 2 are very common in Japanese.

It seems that consonants in ハ行, if after ち or つ　, usually become semi-voiced (半濁) . At the same time, ち or つ become っ (促音化).

- 烈（レツ）+ 風（フウ）-> 烈風（レ**ップ**ウ）

Also, if after ん, these consonants appear to become semi-voiced as well.

- 三（サン）+ 分（フン）->　三分（サン**プ**ン）
- 千（セン）+ 変（ヘン）-> 千変（セン**ペ**ン）

For other consonants, like those in カ行, there doesn't seem to be a general rule, just as @Leebo mentioned. But fortunately, Some cases can be handled using UniDic, a dictionary for Japanese morphological analysis.

Using MeCab and UniDic, we can parse 三階 and 三回, respectively.

```
三      名詞,数詞,*,*,*,*,サン,三,三,サン,三,サン,漢,*,*,*,*,N3,*,数,サン,サン,サン,サン,0,C3,*,3985463396409856,14499
階      名詞,普通名詞,助数詞可能,*,*,*,カイ,階,階,カイ,階,カイ,漢,カ濁,基本形,*,*,*,"B1S6SjShS,B1S6S8SjShS",体,カイ,カイ,カイ,カイ,1,C3,*,1545647094374912,5623
```

```
三      名詞,数詞,*,*,*,*,サン,三,三,サン,三,サン,漢,*,*,*,*,N3,*,数,サン,サン,サン,サン,0,C3,*,3985463396409856,14499
回      名詞,普通名詞,助数詞可能,*,*,*,カイ,回,回,カイ,回,カイ,漢,*,*,*,*,*,"B1S6SjShS,B1S6S8SjShS",体,カイ,カイ,カイ,カイ,1,C3,*,1540974169956864,5606
```

In the above 2 cases, 三 has a feature **N3**, 階 has a feature カ濁, while 回 has *, which means no information. And according to [UniDic User Manual](https://clrd.ninjal.ac.jp/unidic/UNIDIC_manual.pdf), some rules for 濁音化 for numbers are illustrated in a chart.

[image]

According to this chart, we find the rule below:

> If the previous word has a feature of N3 and the next word is カ濁, then consonant (of the next word) **k** becomes **g**.

Thus, 濁音化 happens in 三階 but not in 三回.

And additionally, cases like 3 and 4 are much more tricky. 興味 ends with ミ and 猫 ends with コ. I can't see any point about how they can affect following consonants.

Comment: There are always going to be exceptions. Even with the first one you mentioned, さん + かい = さんがい when talking about 階, but さん + かい = さんかい when talking about 回.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely true. Fortunately, [UniDic](https://clrd.ninjal.ac.jp/unidic/en/) seems to handle this. The features related to 濁音化 of 階 and 回 are different, which are `カ濁,基本形` and `*,*`(no rule) respectively.

Comment: But it seems that UniDic  only handles numbers. So cases like 興味深い are still tricky.

Comment: Can you explain more why you find 3 and 4 less easy to figure out than 1 and 2? Or is this strictly about "less easy to figure out within UniDic"? Which I know nothing about.

Comment: OK! I'll edit my question later.

Comment: @Leebo Hey, I just modified the question with more information~

Answer (score 1):

I have never come across the term 濁音化, but clearly what you describe is called 連濁, translated as 'sequential voicing'. Since Timothy Vance, An Introduction to Japanese Phonology, devotes a whole chapter to this subject, I don't think it can be covered properly here. You should really consult the above-mentioned book, or some other treatment of Japanese phonology. There are some general rules like 'Lyman's Law' which states that a voiced obstruent inhibits rendaku, e.g., oo + sora yields oozora, 大空, but oo + kaze yields ookaze 大風, not the expected *oogaze (because kaze contains a voiced fricative, 'z'), but it is a large topic.